# Stream music like spotify

Tags: ios, streaming, spotify

i'm working on creating an app that streams mp3s from a server. i'm using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer to accomplish this, but noticed that (especially on non-wifi) that it takes a few seconds to buffer and start streaming the audio. I'm looking to minimize this, à la Spotify, which is does it almost instantly.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: My guess would be by holding an open connection, awaiting the selection of music and then "instantly" pushing that selection down the open pipe.  Rather than what you are currently doing which will most likely be establishing a connection after selection.  The latency will certainly be a big killer, if nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spotify does a lot of clever stuff to ensure music streams instantly. I don't know how you're exactly implementing your streaming, but it's worth reading this article to get a handle on what exactly is going on when you 'stream' from Spotify:

http://pansentient.com/2011/04/spotify-technology-some-stats-and-how-spotify-works/

There's a lot of 'nifty' logic going on involving Spotify predicting which tracks you're likely to play in the future and pre-fetching them. Their mobile apps originally didn't take advantage of this to the same extent as the desktop, but I suspect as the apps have matured they've drip-fed some of the platform improvements down to mobile.